Loading selected geometry from GeoParquet with multiple geometry columns into QGIS
I have a GeoParquet file containing two geometry columns ("geom_p_4326" and "geom_4326") and an ID column ("id"). The first geometry column holds points and the second holds boundaries.
I can load this file into QGIS but it always selects the first geometry it finds. I've tried the GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES option feeding in both geoms in a comma-separated list and only one geom name at a time but QGIS still only selects the first geom. I'm on QGIS 3.34.12
Does anyone have any ideas on how to map the second geometry without creating separate files?

The GeoParquet I tested with "multigeom.parquet" has "name", "multipoly_geom" and "centroid_geom"  columns.
Using ogrinfo I can select each geometry column individually:
$ ogrinfo -so -al multigeom.parquet -dialect SQLite \
  -sql 'SELECT name, centroid_geom FROM multigeom'

INFO: Open of `multigeom.parquet'
      using driver `Parquet' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 5
Extent: (-112.599436, -17.316309) - (163.853165, 61.469076)
Layer SRS WKT:
<snip>
Geometry Column = centroid_geom

$ ogrinfo -so -al multigeom.parquet -dialect SQLite \
  -sql 'SELECT name, multipoly_geom FROM multigeom'

INFO: Open of `multigeom.parquet'
      using driver `Parquet' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Multi Polygon
Feature Count: 5
Extent: (-180.000000, -18.287990) - (180.000000, 83.233240)
Layer SRS WKT:
<snip>
Geometry Column = multipoly_geom

I tried creating a QGIS Virtual Layer for each geometry type using those sql expressions but I couldn't get that to work and got a C++ error
Critical: Caught unhandled std::exception:  std::bad_alloc

I then tried an OGR VRT which I created in a text editor and saved as "multigeom.vrt" in the same folder as the GeoParquet:
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="polygons">
        <SrcDataSource>multigeom.parquet</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT name, multipoly_geom from multigeom</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="points">
        <SrcDataSource>multigeom.parquet</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT name, centroid_geom from multigeom</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>

This loads fine into QGIS and you can select one or both geometry types as separate layers:


